# Review of beginner java code

Tags: java

This is a problem I am working on for a sample exam, but can not figure out where I am messing up the code.  Obviously it does not run.  Any hints would be nice.  I am new to java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicketProgram {public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int totalTickets = 100;
    int ticketsPerPerson = 4;

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the total amount of tickets you wish to purchase: (No more than 4) ");
        int ticketsSold = in.nextInt();
        if (ticketsSold > 4){
            System.out.println("Max of 4 ticket.  Please reenter the amount of tickets you want to purchase: ");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You have chosen to purchase " + ticketsSold + " tickets.");
            int ticketsLeft = (totalTickets - ticketsSold);
            System.out.println("There are " + ticketsLeft + " left");

        while (ticketsLeft > 0); {
        if (ticketsLeft == 0)
        System.out.println("There are no tickets left. ");} 

    }
}
```

When compile this program then getting compile time error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - Erroneous tree type:  at
>   TicketProgram.main(TicketProgram.java:19)
>   C:\Users\isaacbrekke\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:‌​53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? Also fix your indentation... Also you have no closing bracket `}` for the `else` statement and the `while(ticketsLeft > 0); {` should not have those brakets

Comment: If you truly expect help you need to provide more details than just "*does not run*".

Comment: Start small, get it to compile and then starting adding bits too it.

Comment: Look at the placement of `{` in your `do-while` statement.

Comment: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
 at TicketProgram.main(TicketProgram.java:19)
C:\Users\isaacbrekke\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)"

Normally if it does not compile I just need to add a }, but this time no matter what I do i can not get it to compile for me to even start troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bracket issue to me. 
You need to close the the brackets on the else statement and the do loop.
Also, those last two lines should not have brackets around them.

```
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter the total amount of tickets you wish to purchase: (No more than 4) ");
    int ticketsSold = in.nextInt();
    if (ticketsSold > 4){
        System.out.println("Max of 4 ticket.  Please reenter the amount of tickets you want to purchase: ");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You have chosen to purchase " + ticketsSold + " tickets.");
        int ticketsLeft = (totalTickets - ticketsSold);
        System.out.println("There are " + ticketsLeft + " left");
    } 
} while (ticketsLeft > 0); 
    if (ticketsLeft == 0)
    System.out.println("There are no tickets left. ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
public class TicketProgram {
   static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int totalTickets = 100;
        int ticketsPerPerson = 4;
        int ticketsLeft = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the total amount of tickets you wish to purchase: (No more than 4) ");
            int ticketsSold = in.nextInt();
            if (ticketsSold > 4){
                System.out.println("Max of 4 ticket.  Please reenter the amount of tickets you want to purchase: ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("You have chosen to purchase " + ticketsSold + " tickets.");
                ticketsLeft = (totalTickets - ticketsSold);
                totalTickets = ticketsLeft;
                System.out.println("There are " + ticketsLeft + " left");
            }}
            while (ticketsLeft > 0); {
            if (ticketsLeft == 0)
            System.out.println("There are no tickets left. ");
            }

        }

        }
```

Comment: initially `ticketsLeft` should not be `0`

Answer (score 1):

In reading your assignment, it looks like you're skipping a crucial part. The assignment asks you to keep track of the number of buyers you have for the 100 tickets. In the code here, I've just added one variable to keep track of the number of buyers, and I only use one variable to keep track of the number of tickets you have left. No need to keep track of both total tickets remaining and total tickets purchased so far. Good luck!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicketSeller {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int tickets = 100;
    int buyers = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(tickets > 0) {
        System.out.println("There are " + tickets + " tickets available.");
        System.out.print("How many would you like to purchase? ");
        int purchase = in.nextInt();
        if (purchase > 0 && purchase <= 4) {
            tickets -= purchase;
            buyers += 1;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, invalid number. Choose between 1 and 4.");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("There were " + buyers + " buyers for the 100 tickets.");
}
```

}

Comment: i did add that in later,except i used count as the variable :)

Answer (score 0):

Brackets are messed up, and code has few logical errors which I fixed for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int totalTickets = 100;

    while (totalTickets > 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the total amount of tickets you wish to purchase: (No more than 4) ");
        int ticketsSold = in.nextInt();
        if (ticketsSold > totalTickets)
        {
            System.out.println("Not enough tickets available. Please reduce and re-enter the amount");
        }
        else if (ticketsSold > 4) {
            System.out.println("Max of 4 ticket.  Please reenter the amount of tickets you want to purchase: ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You have chosen to purchase " + ticketsSold + " tickets.");
            totalTickets = (totalTickets - ticketsSold);
            System.out.println("There are " + totalTickets + " left");
        }
    }

    if (totalTickets == 0)
        System.out.println("There are no tickets left. ");

    in.close();

}
```

Comment: `in.close()`? really? What if the user chooses to use scanner again in the program?

Comment: Is there is a problem?

Comment: No, if you don't use scanner later in the program, and yes if you use later. Take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()). When `close()` is invoked, the underlying `readable` is also closed. Just make sure you have nothing more to read before calling `close()`

Comment: As per OP's code he is obviously not going to use it again.

Comment: In that case it is better to invoke `close()` just as you have to free the resources.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues:

1. Inappropriate use of brackets.
2. `ticketsLeft` used before declaring. (after brackets are corrected)
3. Minor code formatting issues. (ugly use of `main(String[] args)` in the same line as the class declaration)

I suggest you use an IDE (like [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/)) if you are not already using one. Many of your problems would have gone already. (From your comments I came to know you are using NetBeans. Then use the `code formatting` feature, probably by doing a <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, I don't remember the exact shortcut)

Here is a working example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicketProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int totalTickets = 100;
        int ticketsPerPerson = 4;
        int ticketsLeft = totalTickets;

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the total amount of tickets you wish to purchase: (No more than 4) ");
            int ticketsSold = in.nextInt();
            if (ticketsSold > 4){
                System.out.println("Max of 4 ticket.  Please reenter the amount of tickets you want to purchase: ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("You have chosen to purchase " + ticketsSold + " tickets.");
                ticketsLeft = (totalTickets - ticketsSold);
                System.out.println("There are " + ticketsLeft + " left");
            }
        } while (ticketsLeft > 0); 

        if (ticketsLeft == 0) {
            System.out.println("There are no tickets left. ");
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: I had no clue about the formatting feature.  Something neither our book or my teacher has mentioned.  that will come in handy. thanks.

Comment: @IsaacBrekke You should understand that your teacher can't mention everything there is to know; some things you have to learn for yourself. :) Mark the answer as accepted and upvote it if it helped you! Accepting gives you reps too!

Answer (score 0):

This code will help to get your program run without errors and you can improve on this one to have further logic to deal with things like, 'A customer tries to buy 4 tickets when only 3 are left, etc.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TicketProgram {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int totalTickets = 100;
        int ticketsPerPerson = 4;
        int ticketsLeft = totalTickets;

            do {
                System.out.println("Please enter the total amount of tickets you wish to purchase: (No more than 4) ");
                int ticketsSold = in.nextInt();
                if (ticketsSold > ticketsPerPerson){
                    System.out.println("Max of 4 ticket.  Please reenter the amount of tickets you want to purchase: ");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("You have chosen to purchase " + ticketsSold + " tickets.");
                    ticketsLeft = (ticketsLeft - ticketsSold);
                    System.out.println("There are " + ticketsLeft + " left");

                }
                if (ticketsLeft == 0){
                    System.out.println("There are no tickets left. ");
                }


            }while (ticketsLeft > 0);        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an IDE would help is resolving compile errors at the time of coding.

There is one more logic missing in your code. If tickets to buy are more than the total tickets left then your logic would fail. Below is the solution for your question

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicketProgram {
         public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int totalTickets = 100;
    int ticketsPerPerson = 4;
    int ticketsLeft = totalTickets;

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the total amount of tickets you wish to purchase: (No more than 4) ");
        int ticketsSold = in.nextInt();
        if (ticketsSold > 4){
            System.out.println("Max of 4 ticket.  Please reenter the amount of tickets you want to purchase: ");
        }
        else {
            if(ticketsLeft >= ticketsSold){
                System.out.println("You have chosen to purchase " + ticketsSold + " tickets.");
                ticketsLeft = (ticketsLeft - ticketsSold);
                System.out.println("There are " + ticketsLeft + " left");
            }else{

                System.out.println("You have been allocated only " + ticketsLeft + " tickets.");
                ticketsLeft = 0;

            }
        }
    } while (ticketsLeft > 0);

    if (ticketsLeft == 0) {
        System.out.println("There are no tickets left. ");
    }
  }
 }
```